# How to query Firebase users using Firebase admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to query my users using firebase admin. There's a way to list all users but it won't work. I want to query the users. For example, retrieve all users who have `peter` in his display name. How can I do this? The users table is not in the firebase database.

Comment: Do you mean querying from auth or from the real time database or cloud firestore?

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't have a query API.  If you want to do searches or queries, you'll have to write your user data somewhere that can perform the type of query you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the new Admin SDK, you can do like this to fetch all the user from the firebase database. Official link -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

```
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log("user", userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

Comment: Hi can you explain what is the **nextPageToken** here? I am getting the error that nextPageToken not defined

Comment: @Haque Strangely, this is the actual example provided by Google itself.  Their intention is that the first call to `listUsers` should nave the `nextPageToken` as null, which would tell Firebase that there's no offset.  The result of that operation can be `await`ed, or you can follow it with a `then` as in this example.  In any case, the result itself will contain users, and vitally, a `pageToken` attribute, but _only_ if there are multiple pages based upon the initial list size.  The example is 1000, so unless you have >1000 users `pageToken` isn't returned- try lowering that number to see it.

Comment: @bsplosion thanks for the explanation after 2years. I can't remember why I added the comment :D

Answer (score 0):

For `TypeScript` I had to modify the sample code listed @
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users
to:

```js
const listAllUsers = async (nextPageToken: undefined | string) => {

    await admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken).then(async (listUsersResult) => {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
          // do something with userRecord
      });
      
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {                   
          await listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      functions.logger.info('Error listing users:', error);
    });
    
};
await listAllUsers(undefined);
```

Additional details in the `getUsers` method docs:

```js
/**
 * Retrieves a list of users (single batch only) with a size of `maxResults`
 * starting from the offset as specified by `pageToken`. This is used to
 * retrieve all the users of a specified project in batches.
 *
 * See [List all users](/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users)
 * for code samples and detailed documentation.
 *
 * @param maxResults The page size, 1000 if undefined. This is also
 *   the maximum allowed limit.
 * @param pageToken The next page token. If not specified, returns
 *   users starting without any offset.
 * @return A promise that resolves with
 *   the current batch of downloaded users and the next page token.
 */
listUsers(maxResults?: number, pageToken?: string): Promise<ListUsersResult>;
```